# Hibernate create table at runtime

Tags: java, database, spring, postgresql, hibernate

In my database(postgreSQl) is table `Person` which contains `name` and `password`. It is possible to dynamically(at Spring runtime) create new table by using Hibernate? For example I want to create something like single `infoTable` for every `Person` (when `Person` object is created). This table should have name like `Person_Id+"infoTable"`. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: It's not a very good idea to do that. Why would you want a whole separate table for each person?

Comment: @Kayaman I want to totally separate `infotables` (there should be alot of data) and I'm trying to do something new (I have never done it before)

Comment: A better idea is to have a single InfoTable created beforehand, where you store the data for all Persons. That's good database design. Trying to do something new doesn't necessarily mean it's a smart thing to do. In this case I'm almost certain that you're trying to approach this the wrong way. Also, what is your idea of a lot of data? Are you talking about millions of rows? 10s of millions? 100s of millions?

Comment: @Kayaman The main idea was that it should be faster to select single record from `PersonInfoTable` if there are only `info` elements for one `Person` instead elements for every `Person` in one table. So the best way is to create one table for all `infoelements`?

Comment: Yes, the best way is to create one table for infoelements. If you really have *a lot* of data, then there are different approaches that could be used (but none would involve your proposed solution). But will you really have a lot of data in your infotable?

Comment: @Kayaman Probably more than 100.000 `infoelements` for every `Person` (there should be a lot of `Person`). What do you think about this?

Comment: So you'll be in the 10s to 100s of millions of rows. That's not a problem for postgres. If you do end up wanting to divide the data into multiple tables, table partitioning works a lot better than trying to roll your own solution. Don't try to be too clever if you don't have a lot of experience with databases.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate does offer the mode called `EntityMode.MAP` that is excellent for unstructured data.

In order to use `EntityMode.MAP`, you want to create a `Map<String, Object>` structure where the map keys represent the column names and the object represents the value for the associated map key column.  To save such data, you'd use:

> session.save( "the_name_of_my_table", theEntityMap );

While this exists, I don't believe this is ideal for your use case though.

As others have suggested, you'd be better off creating an entity that contains a foreign key back to your `Person` entity and merely manage the multiple rows in a single table.  There are numerous database features that can help easily deal with large volumes of data without having to resort to using `EntityMode.MAP`.

Answer (score -1):

You set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in hibernate configuration, but think twice before doing so.